# Event position not proper fit on days column on moving time in jquery week calendar plugin in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-week-calendar

I have a problem with `event UI` when i am dragging(Not drop yet) `event` first time. It does not move column to column; instead it's dragging like this:

[image]

But once I dropped (it set proper place) that event and again started dragging it so it drags column to column perfectly.

After refreshing the page only the first time this problem occurs.
But if I clicked on today button before dragging any event so it works fine for me even if I drag event the first time.

I found if `_loadCalEvents(new Date());`  function is called this problem is solved (call on today button)

SO please help me how to call this function on my `jsp` page after calendar render.

Comment: What if you refresh the calendar just after the page is tottaly rendered ? Do you still have the glitch ?

Comment: yes after each refresh first time this problem occur (if i click on `today button` before dragging any event first time ,this problem not occur)

Comment: I found that once `_loadCalEvents(date);` is called this is solved and this function call by `Today button `  .. So i wonder hot to call this function on load time

Comment: @U2Answer Can you tell me How Event can be prevented from Dropping at Blocked Business Hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lastly i have solve this by calling

`$('#calendar').weekCalendar("today");`

after `calendar load` .Its render all events for this current week.So solve problem on dragging .

Answer (score 2):

Call `$('#yourCalendarDiv').fullCalendar('render');` **after** rendering your modal/dialog.

> It immediately forces the calendar to render and/or readjusts its
>   size.

Probably, you are creating your calendar before rendering the modal, so the calendar does not know its size. After dragging for the first time, or clicking to switch the view (today button), the calendar is adjusting its size, that's why it works.

Refer to [FullCalendar/Docs/Render](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/)

Comment: `@john` i am using week calendar . So i don't find this method .

Comment: The same is valid, but try with $("#yourDiv").weekCalendar("refresh") instead